# How to increase brightness of laptop screen above maximum in BIOS on Linux/Windows?

Tags: laptop, display, operating-systems, brightness

Is it possible to increase the brightness of laptop screen above what's possible in BIOS and Ubuntu Linux/Windows ?

I have an old laptop (Lenovo-X200s) and the maximum brightness is rather dark. I wish to increase it further beyond what's possible using normal available tools.

I don't care if an increase in brigthness will decrease the lifetime of the laptop, since I need it for most a year.

Can someone provide me with suggestions ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Linux:

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 (your output) --brightness 2 (or the value you want)
```

In Windows:

```
Calibrate your display color (Type "Calibrate display color" in the Windows searchbox)
```

Comment: How do I see my outputs in Ubuntu ? And what is xrandr specifically ?

Comment: And do you know whether this will affect the lifetime out my laptop ?

Comment: I think it should only make the battery usage higher.

Comment: To check the outputs, I think you just do "xrandr". xrandr is just a configuration utility.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helps, but increasing brightness just to 1.02 makes gray more or less white.

Comment: Try in less increments or search for using 'gamma' instead of brightness in xrandr.

Comment: What is the difference between gamma and brightness ?

Comment: [This link](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11445/gamma-vs-brightness-any-difference) explains it very well.

Comment: For me, the command was xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 2 and it worked perfectly for bright sunshine :)

Comment: Hello, I use Windows 10 and the problem is that Calibrating my display colour requires me to use the buttons to adjust brightness that I don't have on my laptop. Is there any way around this? Thanks.

Comment: This does not specifically answer OP's question. With a laptop screen (Win7) already set to have maximum brightness you cannot increase it further via the calibration menu. -1

Comment: This command works for me in Linux, but after about a second it reverts back to 100% brightness :-(